# Bytebuddy - proxy private annotated method

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I am proxying my objects with ByteBuddy and all works fine. When i annotate a method with @Test then they should be proxied another way. So i decided to separate my InvocationHandler into two. So far so good.

But now, when i want to add private, @Test-annotated methods they wont get proxied/intercepted. Only public methods will be intercepted. Any ideas why?

```
// return created proxy instance
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Class<T> proxy = (Class<T>) byteBuddy
    .subclass(clazz)
    .implement(Proxy.class)
    .defineField("_origin", Object.class, Visibility.PRIVATE)
    .defineConstructor(Visibility.PUBLIC)
    .withParameter(Object.class)
    .intercept(MethodCall.invoke(clazz.getDeclaredConstructor()).andThen(FieldAccessor.ofField("_origin").setsArgumentAt(0)))
    .name(clazz.getSimpleName() + "Proxy")
    .method(ElementMatchers.isAnnotatedWith(Test.class))
    .intercept(InvocationHandlerAdapter.of(testInvocationHandler))
    .method(ElementMatchers.isDeclaredBy(AdditionalTest.class))
    .intercept(InvocationHandlerAdapter.of(testInvocationHandler.getAdditionalTestInvocationHandler()))
    .method(ElementMatchers.isDeclaredBy(Proxy.class)).intercept(InvocationHandlerAdapter.of(testInvocationHandler.getAdditionalTestInvocationHandler())).make()
    .load(clazz.getClassLoader()).getLoaded();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define custom methods, your matchers will not be applied to those. You would need to specify the `Implementation` to also apply these matchers. Alternatively, you can create a class with the additional methods and then intercept this type by creating another proxy.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But what do you mean with “custom” methods? I add public custom methods and it works. If I add private custom methods it doesn’t. I don’t get the difference.

Comment: Rafael, i hope we do understand each other correctly. Its' about intercepting custom methods that are annotated with "@Test". If they are public it works as expected. Now i am adding a private @Test-annotated method, the method won't be intercepted.

Comment: I see, you cannot intercept methods that are private. Those methods are not dispatched virtually, they are only declared within the super class.

Comment: Ok understood. Any idea or workaround for solving my issue? I do need also proxying private methods.

Comment: You can instrument a class using an `AgentBuilder`. By rebasing a class, you can intercept private methods.

Comment: That was my thought too today. But, as we aren’t allowed to change jvm configuration this seems not to be a valid option.

Comment: Have a look. at ByteBuddyAgent what helps to avoid this.